# File descriptors in C

Tags: c, file, posix

Let's suppose that in my OS exists N file descriptors. How many file descriptors will OS have after executing the code below:

```
    int fd = dup(oldfd);
```

How about :

```
   int fd = dup2(oldfd,newfd);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its given in man pages. You'll have `N+1` file descriptors after calling either one of them.

```
From manpages
    ...
    dup and dup2 create a copy of the file descriptor oldfd.

    After successful return of dup or dup2, the old and new descriptors 
    may be used interchangeably. 

    dup uses the lowest-numbered unused descriptor for the new descriptor.
    ...
```

So, an unused descriptor is used as a new one. That should answer your question.